# Invert vector position transformation

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, vector

Help me please to solve this problem:
I have a vector A and I get vector B this way:

```
B = M1 * A * 0.5 + M2 * A * 0.5;
```

M1 - rotation matrix 0 deg.

M2 - rotation Matrix 45 deg.

I need to get a way to compute A if B is known. For instance if B == (0.8535, 0.3535), then A should be (1.0, 0.0). How can I get the inverted formula?

UPD: for 0.4/0.6 the result formula is:

```
A=(M1*0.4+M2*0.6)^-1 * B
```

Comment: Multiplication is distributive over addition: 0.5 M1 A + 0.5 M2 A = 0.5 (M1+M2) A.

Comment: You can get the "inverted formula" by literally inverting the matrix: if (M1 + M2) is invertible, then B = 0.5 (M1 + M2) A is equivalent to A = 2 (M1 + M2)^-1 B, where `^-1` denotes matrix inversion.

Comment: However, since you ask this on StackOverflow, I assume it's a programming problem. Rather than searching for "matrix inverse" on a matrix library, you can look for a linear equation solver. There is usually a function `solve` such that `solve(0.5 (M1 + M2), B)` is the vector A you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Stef, that works. How did you get the "2" ? What should I place there if the coefficients are 0.4 and 0.6, for instance?

Comment: 2 is the inverse of 0.5. That is, 2*0.5=1, or another way to look at it, 1/2=0.5 and 1/0.5 = 2. The inverse of 0.4 is 1/0.4 = 1/(4/10) = 10/4 = 5/2 = 2.5.

Comment: Should the result for 0.4 and 0.6 look like this: ((1/0.4) * M1 + (1/0.6) *M2)^-1 * B or the matrices can't be multiplied before inversion? I tried it in the code, but the result seems to be not absolutely correct.

Comment: Yes, `((1/0.4) * M1 + (1/0.6) *M2)^-1 * B` looks correct

Answer (score 2):

Bring this equation into a single matrix-vector product

```
B = M1 * A * 0.5 + M2 * A * 0.5
B = (M1 * 0.5 + M2 * 0.5)*A
B = M*A
```

and invert `M`

```
A = inv(M)*B = M\B
```

For example

```
M1 = | 1   0 |          M2 = | 1/√2  -1/√2 |
     | 0   1 |               | 1/√2   1/√2 |
```

makes

```
M = | √2/4+1/2      -√2/4 |
    | √2/4       √2/4+1/2 |
```

and the inverse

```
inv(M) = | 1      √2-1 |
         | 1-√2      1 |
```

you will find that

```
 inv(M)*| 0.8535 | = |  0.999999  |
        | 0.3535 |   |  -3e-5     |
```

The above process is part of linear algebra, exactly because you can use the associative & distributive properties with non-scalar quantities.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = (M1 * 0.5 + M2 * 0.5)^-1 * B
```